# Mediawiki wikitable default sorting in descending order

Tags: mediawiki

I have something like

```
{| class="wikitable sortable"
|-
! Year || Country
|-
| 2000 || US
|-
| 2001 || Japan
|-
| 1999 || Germanay
|}
```

But I want this will appear in wiki page automatically in descending order of year, even if I put 2000 before 2001.

Can I choose such "default" for wikitable ordering?

Answer (score 2):

[No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aSorting#Initial_sort_order_of_rows).

But if you haven't disabled `MediaWiki/Common.js`, you could rearrange the table on pageload with JavaScript. See also [https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Sorting#Default_order](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aSorting#Default_order) (“It is not possible to make a table appear sorted by a certain column without the user clicking on it.”)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with Semantic MediaWiki. The data shown in your table must be stored as semantic properties. Use `#ask` to query the data, with parameters `sort=SomePropertyName` and `order=desc`. See here for more: https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Inline_queries